# Why is 1-ethylcyclohexene more stable than ethylidene cyclohexane?

Tags: organic-chemistry, stability, hydrocarbons, cyclohexane, ring-strain

Both compounds yield the same product, ethylcyclohexane, when hydrogenated. However,
1-ethylcyclohexene has lesser heat of hydrogenation than ethylidenecyclohexane, hence more stable. I want to know why that is the case although both are trisubstituted. (I can only think of comparing them as cyclohexane ring vs cyclohexene.)

Please note: I am trying to learn Chemistry to teach my child. I left chemistry a long time ago and am now refreshing the topics.

Comment: In general, exocyclic double bonds are less stable than endocyclic double bonds for six-membered rings. Plus, since hyperconjugation stabilizes double bonds, one must note that the number of $\alpha$ H are more for 1-ethylcyclohexene and hence, it is comparatively more stable.